# How to update a function with useEffect (like componentDidUpdate) and use .map function to display from JSON file ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been trying to update a function once data has been recieved and set to a state (using useState). After that the function will use the .map function display the data into a template.

However i am getting two errors, one is 'projects.map is not a function' (btw projects is my state name, where data is stored) and inside the useEffect function which updates when projects is changed 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ProjectSummary from './projectSummary';


function ProjectList() {

  // setting my state
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

  // getting the data from some dummy online data when the app     starts
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setProjects({ data }))

  }, []);

    // makeing a function call postList, which stores a ternery     operator
    const postList = () => {
    // The ternery operator asks if there is anything inside the porjects state
      projects.length ? (
      // If there is something in the state, it will map out the JSON array in the 'projectSummary template
        projects.map(projects => {
          return(
            <div >
              <ProjectSummary key={projects.id} title={projects.title} author={projects.userId} date='30 september, 2019' content={projects.body}/>

            </div>
          )
        })
      ) : (
      // If there isnt anything in the state is prints out 'Loading Data'
        <h1>Loading Data</h1>
      );
    }
    
    
    // useEffect updates when the 'projects' stae is updated (like componentDidUpdate, and runs the function again
    useEffect(() => {
   
      postList()
   
    }, [projects]);


  return(
    <div className="ProjectList">
    
      // The component should output the postList function, which should map out the array, in the template
      { postList }


    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectList
```

Comment: `postList` function returns nothing. The second `useEffect` looks unnecessary. Mapping inline in the returned JSX should be enough.

Comment: You can check my answer. Quite similar to what @EmileBergeron has mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make some corrections to your component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ProjectSummary from './projectSummary';


function ProjectList() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setProjects(data))

  }, []);


  return(
    <div className="ProjectList">
      {
        projects.length ?
          projects.map(projects => (
            <div>
              <ProjectSummary key={projects.id} title={projects.title} author={projects.userId} date='30 september, 2019' content={projects.body} />
            </div>
          ))
          :
          <h1>Loading Data</h1>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectList;
```

You don't need the `postList` function and the second `useEffect`.

You may want to add additional checks to determine when the posts are loading and when they're empty after loading is done, so you don't just get a loading message

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
```

and

```
.then(data => setProjects(data))
```

assuming that the **data** is an array

Comment: I am stuck on the 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression', which if i remove the useEffect which calls the 'postList' function, it then says .length isn't a function, in the ternary operator. But I want the function to reload once the state has changed

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the initial projects to an empty array like this:

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
```

, because currently projects is an empty string, which does not have the map function.

For the fetch, you should write it like this:

```
 useEffect(async () => {
     const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
       .then(response => response.json())
     setProjects(data);
}, []);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but the receiving of the data works, it's only the recalling function 'postList' in the useEffect doesn't work.

Comment: When and how often do you want to call the useEffect exactly?

Comment: it should be called once, which is when the data is received

Comment: you should move the  whole projects.map into your rendering/return of the component. That way you don't have to keep track of the postList. This way only the projects in your useState are the source of truth. if you really want to use the postList object (not recommended), you have to return it like this: return projects.map(...);

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map() is for Array.

const [projects, setProjects] = useState('');

projects not an array.